# Como exportar en jpg un mapa de vertex paint de una escultura 3d

Tags: texture-painting, vertex-groups

E esculpido una cabeza pterodactilo y lo pinte en modo vertex paint y quiero exportar en jpg la pintura de vertices del unwrap

Comment: Please post answers in English

Comment: Mandatory language for stack exchange is English, if you are not fluent just use some online translation system